# How to host Laravel 5.4 application on server?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-artisan

I have created an application in laravel 5.4 and I'm running it using 
**php artisan serve**.  Now I want to host it on live server. I have some question about this.

1. How can we build Laravel app to host on the production server? (just like Angular 2/4).
2. Do we always need artisan serve to run the application?
3. How to communicate local development and remote development via FTP or same?

Comment: `php artisan serve` is for development not for live

Comment: Chris Fidao has a very good tutorial that will take you from start to finish if you are interested in cloud hosting. Just used it to host a Laravel app the other night. You can find it .....

[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQNrsMYCOFg)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the answers of your question

1. How can we build Laravel app to host on the production server? (just like Angular 2/4).

   You need to deploy all your files exclude vendor directory, composer.json,storage. After deployment you need to run below command

   - `composer update`
   - `composer dump-autoload`
2. Do we always need artisan serve to run the application?

   - No, You need to create DNS and it should point to your public directory.
3. How to communicate local development and remote development via FTP or same.

   - There are many ways, you can choose what you are comfortable with, like,  You can use FTP or you can use version control like Git etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i highly recommend read [Laravel Deployment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/deployment) document, that added in 5.5 documents.

Why we use from "php artisan serve":
in the local development we have 2 way to see result of our scripts.

1. define a domain in local and point that to public directory of your site.
2. use "php artisan serve" command and word imminently after getting the script.

in the remote server you just need to point public directory.

About number 3: you can first compress your files and upload to your remote server and uncompressed that in server with tools of remote server.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How can we build laravel app to host on the production server?(just like angular 2/4).

You need a web server like apache or nginx or light httpd, then you should create a virtual host to host your project code.

> 2. Do we always need artisan serve to run the application?

No.  artisan serve is just a fast demonstration tool for local test. It can't supervise file modifications so you should never use it in dev or production.

> 3. How to communicate local development and remote development via FTP or same.

Some IDE can help you to synchronize files between local and remote environment like zend studio or phpstorm(itellij studio).

Try that but pay attention to file access privilege (think of difference between 755 and 644 )

but git is always the best way to keep your production code clean.